# How to implement localStorage syncer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I want to implement my useLocalStorage file with my App.js but i'm having trouble understanding how to do so, as I'm still learning.

useLocalStorage.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


function useLocalStorage(key, firstValue = null) {
    const initialValue = localStorage.getItem(key) || firstValue;
  
    const [item, setItem] = useState(initialValue);
  
    useEffect(function setKeyInLocalStorage() {
      console.debug("hooks useLocalStorage useEffect", "item=", item);
  
      if (item === null) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(key, item);
      }
    }, [key, item]);
  
    return [item, setItem];
  }
  
  export default useLocalStorage;
```

App.js

```
import useLocalStorage from "./hooks/useLocalStorage";

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(axios());
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <LastLocationProvider>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes />
        <Footer />
      </LastLocationProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Any tips or knowledge that you can pass would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generally looks good to me. Are you experiencing a specific error?

Comment: I need to implement useLocalStorage function with the App.js file within useEffect. More specifically, i'm trying to use this to check if a token is present and if so render App. if not then do nothing.

Comment: Sounds like you just want `const [token, setToken] = useLocalStorage('your_key_here', 'your_default_token_here')`, right? Similar syntax to `useState()` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: So would I just add that under the useEffect in the App.js? if so, my second questions is i've already implemented useEffect inside of useLocalStorage, will that cause issues with adding it within another useEffect? I want the token to be empty to start, then accept the users token when entered so is that

`useLocalStorage('token', 'null')`
?

Comment: You can't use a `useEffect` within another `useEffect` but you can add it after your current `useEffect` in `App`, yes. For an empty token, I would recommend `''`, not `'null`.

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. So to understand what you've said. I need to add `const [token, setToken] = useLocalStorage('token', ' ')` after `useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(axios());
  }, []);` to implement it?

Comment: Yes, although order doesn't actually matter since it doesn't seem like they interact with each other.